# Graph problems when producing interactive plots using matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, graph

I was trying to produce an interactive plot with a slider.
But when I move the slider, the peak height of the graph ceased to become 1.
According to Desmos the graph should be like this:
[Graph of the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGpH8.png)

With no change of peak height, only change in x value for the peak when the value inside cosine changes.
Are there any problems in the coding of the graph? As the function is quite complex.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel("L")
ax.set_xlabel("Energy in keV")
ax.set_title("Output graph for change of spectrum with the detection angle")
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(10, 20.0, 0.01)
a0 = 0
s = 0.01/(0.01+2*np.power(((1/((1/t)-((1-np.cos(a0)))/512))-17),2))
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
ax.margins(x=0)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axamp = plt.axes([0.25, 0.09, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

samp = Slider(axamp, 'Detection angle',0.0, 180.0,valstep=5, valinit=a0)

def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    l.set_ydata(0.1/(0.1+2*np.power(((1/((1/t)-(1-np.cos(amp))/512))-17),2)))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()

samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    samp.reset()
button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.13, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)


def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()
radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

colorfunc(radio.value_selected)

plt.show()
```

I am quite new to programming in Python so forgive me if there are any mistakes.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `np.cos(amp)` to `np.cos(np.deg2rad(amp))` (This is because, np.cos expects the input angles in radians)

Also, I think you should have a `+` after `(1/t)` in the formula you are calculation based on the image you've linked to in the post.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylabel("L")
ax.set_xlabel("Energy in keV")
ax.set_title("Output graph for change of spectrum with the detection angle")
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.25, bottom=0.25)
t = np.arange(10, 20.0, 0.01)
a0 = 0
# 0 radians or 0 degress doesn't matter so you can neglect conversion here
s = 0.01 / (0.01 + 2 * np.power(((1 / ((1 / t) + ((1 - np.cos(a0))) / 512)) - 17), 2))
l, = plt.plot(t, s, lw=2)
ax.margins(x=0)
axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
axamp = plt.axes([0.25, 0.09, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

samp = Slider(axamp, 'Detection angle', 0.0, 180.0, valstep=5, valinit=a0)


def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    l.set_ydata(0.1 / (0.1 + 2 * np.power(((1 / ((1 / t) + (1 - np.cos(np.deg2rad(amp))) / 512)) - 17), 2)))
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


samp.on_changed(update)

resetax = plt.axes([0.8, 0.025, 0.1, 0.04])
button = Button(resetax, 'Reset', color=axcolor, hovercolor='0.975')


def reset(event):
    samp.reset()


button.on_clicked(reset)

rax = plt.axes([0.025, 0.5, 0.13, 0.15], facecolor=axcolor)
radio = RadioButtons(rax, ('red', 'blue', 'green'), active=0)


def colorfunc(label):
    l.set_color(label)
    fig.canvas.draw_idle()


radio.on_clicked(colorfunc)

colorfunc(radio.value_selected)

plt.show()
```

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? The signal is just supposed to move along x axis right?

Comment: Or you want the peak height to vary keeping the position constant?

Comment: Sorry for the plus minus sign but this didn't effect the behavior too much, only the x-direction of the peak moving. For me after moving the slider the peak disappears and the graph is just a horizontal line near zero. With random peaks occurs but not at the height of 1.

Comment: That is weird. I think I have the right behaviour with peak moving between x=17 and x=18. Try to run my code

Comment: Your code solved the problem! What did you changed? Maybe my typing of the equation do have problems...

Comment: My only changes were 1) changing minus sign to plus sign 2) changing `np.cos(amp)` to `np.cos(np.deg2rad(amp))` inside the update function. If your problem is solved, consider accepting the solution.

Comment: Maybe I know what is the problem...maybe the accuracy is not enough,I think I will try to increase the sensitivity to what I wanted ( actually the smallest term I needed is 0.00000001),and tighten the range to as small as possible to prevent my PC from crashing.